# Cassandra, Titan, Fatal configuration error

Tags: java, linux, cassandra, titan

I tried starting titan with cassandra (linux):

```
TitanFactory.Builder config = TitanFactory.build();

config.set("storage.backend", "embeddedcassandra");
config.set("storage.directory", DIRECTORY);
config.set("index." + INDEX_NAME + ".backend", "elasticsearch");
config.set("index." + INDEX_NAME + ".DIRECTORY", DIRECTORY + File.separator + "es");
config.set("index." + INDEX_NAME + ".elasticsearch.local-mode", true);
config.set("index." + INDEX_NAME + ".elasticsearch.client-only", false);

graph = config.open();
```

Getting the following log:

> 09:57:50.195 [main] ERROR o.a.c.config.DatabaseDescriptor - Fatal
>   configuration error
>   org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Expecting URI
>   in variable: [cassandra.config].  Please prefix the file with file:///
>   for local files or file:/// for remote files. Aborting. If you
>   are executing this from an external tool, it needs to set
>   Config.setClientMode(true) to avoid loading configuration.    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.getStorageConfigURL(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:73)
>   ~[cassandra-all-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]  at
>   org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:84)
>   ~[cassandra-all-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]  at
>   org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:161)
>   ~[cassandra-all-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]  at
>   org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.(DatabaseDescriptor.java:136)
>   ~[cassandra-all-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]  at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:164)
>   [cassandra-all-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:537)
>   [cassandra-all-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:626)
>   [cassandra-all-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]   at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.utils.CassandraDaemonWrapper.start(CassandraDaemonWrapper.java:75)
>   [titan-cassandra-1.0.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.embedded.CassandraEmbeddedStoreManager.(CassandraEmbeddedStoreManager.java:81)
>   [titan-cassandra-1.0.0.jar:na]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   [na:1.8.0_112]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   [na:1.8.0_112]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   [na:1.8.0_112]    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   [na:1.8.0_112]    at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:44)
>   [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:473)
>   [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:407)
>   [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1320)
>   [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
>   [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:84)
>   [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder.open(TitanFactory.java:139)
>   [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   main.java.com.bag.server.database.TitanDatabaseAccess.start(TitanDatabaseAccess.java:68)
>   [main/:na]    at
>   main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.(TestServer.java:105)
>   [main/:na]    at
>   main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.main(TestServer.java:428)
>   [main/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>   [idea_rt.jar:na]

Answer (score 4):

Embedded Cassandra requires you to specify where it can find its configuration file (cassandra.yaml). From the [documentation](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/cassandra.html#_titan_embedded_mode):

> When running Titan in embedded mode, the Cassandra yaml file is
>   configured using the additional configuration option
>   storage.conf-file, which specifies the yaml file as a full url, e.g.
>   storage.conf-file = file:///home/cassandra.yaml.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve and as you are anyways not running fully in-memory (Elasticsearch) you might consider to use `berkeleyje` as your storage backend. Berkeley DB for Titan is essentially zero config. All you need is to do is specify the storage directory. E.g.

```
storage.backend=berkeleyje
storage.directory=${java.io.tmpdir}/${storage.dir}
```

Of course you are free to place the storage directory wherever you like.

The [index backend](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/index-backends.html) is independent of the persistence backend and requires its own configuration, depending on wich backend you choose. Again, depending on what you are trying to achieve you could start without. Indexes for equality comparisons are [natively supported](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html) by Titan, you do not need an external search index for that. 
Beware of this open [Titan issue](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/788). The search index is not guaranteed to be in sync with the graph at all times.

Comment: As I am going to run some benchmarks on my project.
What is the fastest storage backend?

Comment: That depends on your usage patterns. E.g. C* is optimized for write-heavy workloads. At the same time it is not so good if you regularly delete a lot of data. As Titan never updates an edge but rather deletes and re-creates them, this would not be a good usage pattern for a C* backend. I'd simply start with the backend that is easiest to use. Which would be the `inmemory` and `berkeleyje` storage backends.

Comment: I'm going to read, write, delete a lot of nodes and relationships. Probably a lot of read. I have to use java to access it though.

Comment: As I said, I'd start simple. What language you use has little relevance for choosing a storage backend.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find implementation class: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex

Getting this exception now with the config you said.

Comment: It seems like the problem wasn't cassandra, it is elastricsearch and log4j

Comment: If you need Elasticsearch you need to configure it of course. I gave you the relevant config for Berkeley DB. The [search indexer](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/index-backends.html) is independent of the storage backend you use and requires its configuration, of course. Also, you need to put the implementation on the classpath.

Comment: Actually, elasticsearch crashes even if I define no search indexer at all and just use the blank config. I loaded everything with maven should be all there.

Comment: Elasticsearch is a separate server process. The titan configuration related to Elesticsearch only tells Titan how to connect with it. If you have problems running Elasticsearcht, then you need to check their documentation for help.

Comment: It seems like titan got generally problems connecting to the code, even if not using it directly:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688106/titan-loading-problems-with-elastic-search