# Titan loading problems with elastic search

Tags: java, linux, elasticsearch, titan, berkeley-db

I'm using the following code to load Titan:

```
TitanFactory.Builder config = TitanFactory.build();
    config.set("storage.backend", "berkeleyje");
    config.set("storage.directory", DIRECTORY);
    //config.set("storage.conf-file", "file:////" + DIRECTORY + "/cassandra/cassandra.yaml");
    config.set("index." + INDEX_NAME + ".backend", "elasticsearch");
    config.set("index." + INDEX_NAME + ".DIRECTORY", DIRECTORY + File.separator + "es");
    config.set("index." + INDEX_NAME + ".elasticsearch.local-mode", true);
    config.set("index." + INDEX_NAME + ".elasticsearch.client-only", false);

    graph = config.open();
```

loading dependencies with gradle:

```
compile group: 'com.thinkaurelius.titan', name: 'titan-all', version: '1.0.0'
```

My project directory is:

/home/ray/IdeaProjects/BAG - Byzantine fault-tolerant Architecture for Graph database/

my titan is in this project directory in the folder "TITAN"
That's what I set in the Directory variable.

Still on start it always crashes:

```
22:56:01.420 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.d.b.BerkeleyJEStoreManager - Opened database system_properties
java.lang.Throwable: null
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEStoreManager.openDatabase(BerkeleyJEStoreManager.java:172) [titan-berkeleyje-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEStoreManager.openDatabase(BerkeleyJEStoreManager.java:34) [titan-berkeleyje-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.keyvalue.OrderedKeyValueStoreManagerAdapter.openDatabase(OrderedKeyValueStoreManagerAdapter.java:76) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.keyvalue.OrderedKeyValueStoreManagerAdapter.openDatabase(OrderedKeyValueStoreManagerAdapter.java:69) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.keyvalue.OrderedKeyValueStoreManagerAdapter.openDatabase(OrderedKeyValueStoreManagerAdapter.java:25) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStandaloneGlobalConfiguration(Backend.java:449) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1322) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:84) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder.open(TitanFactory.java:139) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at main.java.com.bag.server.database.TitanDatabaseAccess.start(TitanDatabaseAccess.java:56) [main/:na]
    at main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.<init>(TestServer.java:105) [main/:na]
    at main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.main(TestServer.java:428) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
22:56:01.423 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.d.k.k.OrderedKeyValueStoreAdapter - Used key length 0 for database system_properties
22:56:01.429 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader$LoaderConfiguration - Option loading enabled by default
22:56:01.431 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Added preferred classloader to config option loader chain: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.431 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Added thread context classloader to config option loader chain: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.431 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Added caller classloader to config option loader chain: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.442 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Loaded class com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager with loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.442 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Located functioning classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee; using it for remaining classload attempts
22:56:01.447 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Loaded class com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager with selected loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.447 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Loaded class com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.AbstractCassandraStoreManager with selected loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.452 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Loaded class com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager with selected loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.459 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Loaded class com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex with selected loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.460 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Unable to load class com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.solr.SolrIndex with selected loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.solr.SolrIndex
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.util.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader.loadStandard(ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader.java:136) ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.ConfigNamespace.getChild(ConfigNamespace.java:68) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.ConfigElement.parse(ConfigElement.java:180) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.BasicConfiguration.getAll(BasicConfiguration.java:80) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1327) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:84) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder.open(TitanFactory.java:139) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at main.java.com.bag.server.database.TitanDatabaseAccess.start(TitanDatabaseAccess.java:56) [main/:na]
    at main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.<init>(TestServer.java:105) [main/:na]
    at main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.main(TestServer.java:428) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
22:56:01.462 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Loaded class com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog with selected loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.463 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Loaded class com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLogManager with selected loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.463 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Loaded class com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration with selected loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.464 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Loaded class com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.placement.SimpleBulkPlacementStrategy with selected loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.465 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Loaded class com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idassigner.VertexIDAssigner with selected loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.465 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Loaded class com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEStoreManager with selected loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.465 [main] INFO  c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Loaded and initialized config classes: 11 OK out of 12 attempts in PT0.035S
22:56:01.466 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Added preferred classloader to config option loader chain: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.466 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Added thread context classloader to config option loader chain: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.466 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Added caller classloader to config option loader chain: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63e31ee
22:56:01.493 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - going to scan these urls:
file:/home/ray/IdeaProjects/BAG%20-%20Byzantine%20fault-tolerant%20Architecture%20for%20Graph%20database/build/classes/main/
22:56:01.497 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file main/java/com/bag/server/TestServer.class in url file:/home/ray/IdeaProjects/BAG%20-%20Byzantine%20fault-tolerant%20Architecture%20for%20Graph%20database/build/classes/main/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
22:56:01.497 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file main/java/com/bag/server/TestServer.class in url file:/home/ray/IdeaProjects/BAG%20-%20Byzantine%20fault-tolerant%20Architecture%20for%20Graph%20database/build/classes/main/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
22:56:01.497 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file main/java/com/bag/server/ConflictHandler.class in url file:/home/ray/IdeaProjects/BAG%20-%20Byzantine%20fault-tolerant%20Architecture%20for%20Graph%20database/build/classes/main/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
22:56:01.498 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file main/java/com/bag/server/ConflictHandler.class in url file:/home/ray/IdeaProjects/BAG%20-%20Byzantine%20fault-tolerant%20Architecture%20for%20Graph%20database/build/classes/main/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
22:56:01.502 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file main/java/com/bag/server/database/Neo4jDatabaseAccess.class in url file:/home/ray/IdeaProjects/BAG%20-%20Byzantine%20fault-tolerant%20Architecture%20for%20Graph%20database/build/classes/main/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
22:56:01.503 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file main/java/com/bag/server/database/Neo4jDatabaseAccess.class in url file:/home/ray/IdeaProjects/BAG%20-%20Byzantine%20fault-tolerant%20Architecture%20for%20Graph%20database/build/classes/main/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
22:56:01.506 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file main/java/com/bag/server/database/OrientDBDatabaseAccess.class in url file:/home/ray/IdeaProjects/BAG%20-%20Byzantine%20fault-tolerant%20Architecture%20for%20Graph%20database/build/classes/main/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
22:56:01.506 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file main/java/com/bag/server/database/OrientDBDatabaseAccess.class in url file:/home/ray/IdeaProjects/BAG%20-%20Byzantine%20fault-tolerant%20Architecture%20for%20Graph%20database/build/classes/main/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
22:56:01.508 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file main/java/com/bag/client/TestClient.class in url file:/home/ray/IdeaProjects/BAG%20-%20Byzantine%20fault-tolerant%20Architecture%20for%20Graph%20database/build/classes/main/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
22:56:01.508 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file main/java/com/bag/client/TestClient.class in url file:/home/ray/IdeaProjects/BAG%20-%20Byzantine%20fault-tolerant%20Architecture%20for%20Graph%20database/build/classes/main/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
22:56:01.516 [main] INFO  org.reflections.Reflections - Reflections took 22 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 6 keys and 13 values 
22:56:01.518 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.c.u.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader - Preloaded 0 config option(s) via Reflections (0 class(es) with errors)
22:56:01.518 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.d.c.BasicConfiguration - Ignored configuration entry for index.search.DIRECTORY since it does not map to an option
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown configuration element in namespace [root.index]: DIRECTORY
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.ConfigElement.parse(ConfigElement.java:181) ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.BasicConfiguration.getAll(BasicConfiguration.java:80) ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1327) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:84) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder.open(TitanFactory.java:139) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at main.java.com.bag.server.database.TitanDatabaseAccess.start(TitanDatabaseAccess.java:56) [main/:na]
    at main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.<init>(TestServer.java:105) [main/:na]
    at main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.main(TestServer.java:428) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
22:56:01.557 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.d.c.BasicConfiguration - Ignored configuration entry for index.search.DIRECTORY since it does not map to an option
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown configuration element in namespace [root.index]: DIRECTORY
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.ConfigElement.parse(ConfigElement.java:181) ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.BasicConfiguration.getAll(BasicConfiguration.java:80) ~[titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1383) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:84) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder.open(TitanFactory.java:139) [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at main.java.com.bag.server.database.TitanDatabaseAccess.start(TitanDatabaseAccess.java:56) [main/:na]
    at main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.<init>(TestServer.java:105) [main/:na]
    at main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.main(TestServer.java:428) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
22:56:01.563 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.d.b.BerkeleyJEStoreManager - Removed database system_properties
22:56:01.613 [main] INFO  c.t.t.g.c.GraphDatabaseConfiguration - Generated unique-instance-id=c0a8000d21256-Laptop1
22:56:01.641 [main] INFO  c.t.titan.diskstorage.Backend - Configuring index [search]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:55)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:473)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getIndexes(Backend.java:460)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.<init>(Backend.java:147)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1805)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.<init>(StandardTitanGraph.java:123)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:84)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder.open(TitanFactory.java:139)
    at main.java.com.bag.server.database.TitanDatabaseAccess.start(TitanDatabaseAccess.java:56)
    at main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.<init>(TestServer.java:105)
    at main.java.com.bag.server.TestServer.main(TestServer.java:428)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:44)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_3_6
    at org.elasticsearch.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:43)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex.checkExpectedClientVersion(ElasticSearchIndex.java:1059)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex.<init>(ElasticSearchIndex.java:186)
    ... 21 more
```

My gradle file:

```
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile files('libs/BFT-SMaRt.jar')
    compile "org.neo4j:neo4j-enterprise:${neo4jVersion}"
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.5'
    compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.0.36.Final'
    compile group: 'com.thinkaurelius.titan', name: 'titan-all', version: '1.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.sparsity', name: 'sparkseejava', version: '5.2.0'
    compile group: 'com.orientechnologies', name: 'orientdb-graphdb', version: '2.2.11'
    compile group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs', name: 'jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec', version: '1.0.0.Final'
    compile group: 'com.esotericsoftware', name: 'kryo', version: '4.0.0'
    compile 'com.intellij:annotations:+@jar'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tinkerpop', name: 'gremlin-core', version: '3.0.0.M9-incubating'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more specific on your Titan dependencies so you don't pull in unintended artifacts. Instead of using `titan-all`, try something like this:

```
compile group: 'com.thinkaurelius.titan', name: 'titan-berkeleyje', version: '1.0.0'
compile group: 'com.thinkaurelius.titan', name: 'titan-es', version: '1.0.0'
```

You should not need to include `gremlin-core` explicitly because it is a dependency of `titan-core`, however if you do add it, it should be aligned with the [TinkerPop version](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0/pom.xml#L62) that Titan 1.0 uses:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.tinkerpop', name: 'gremlin-core', version: '3.0.1-incubating'
```

***Updated***

Your previous failed attempts have likely created an invalid graph instance stored under `DIRECTORY`. You must recursively remove `DIRECTORY` before attempting to create a new graph using the same directory.

Elasticsearch indexing backend does not work with a `index.search.DIRECTORY` configuration (note the case). This is the relevant part of the stack trace:

> Ignored configuration entry for index.search.DIRECTORY since it does not map to an option
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown configuration element in namespace [root.index]: DIRECTORY

You can read more about the various Elasticsearch configuration options in [Chapter 22](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/elasticsearch.html) of the Titan documentation.

Instead of Elasticsearch, consider using [Lucene](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/lucene.html). Its configuration looks similar to BerkeleyJE storage, and both are well-suited for a single-machine Titan.

```
TitanFactory.Builder config = TitanFactory.build();
config.set("storage.backend", "berkeleyje");
config.set("storage.directory", DIRECTORY + File.separator + "berkeleyje");
config.set("index." + INDEX_NAME + ".backend", "lucene");
config.set("index." + INDEX_NAME + ".directory", DIRECTORY + File.separator + "lucene");
graph = config.open();
```

Also update `build.gradle` with the dependency for lucene:

```
compile group: 'com.thinkaurelius.titan', name: 'titan-berkeleyje', version: '1.0.0'
compile group: 'com.thinkaurelius.titan', name: 'titan-lucene', version: '1.0.0'
```

I'd also recommend trying to build a Titan project without Neo4j, OrientDB, Sparksee, and other non-Titan dependencies first to ensure you have a simple project that works without any dependency conflicts.

Comment: removing the directory and updating the dependencies resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a classpath issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_3_6 at org.elasticsearch.Version.(Version.java:43)
```

Titan-es 1.0.0 depends on Elasticsearch 1.5.1 which again depends on Lucene 4.10.4 which has a deprecated field `org.apache.lucene.util.Version.LUCENE_3_6`. This field was removed in later versions of Lucene. You need to check your classpath and make sure you are pulling in the correct version of Lucene.

Comment: So the "compile group: 'com.thinkaurelius.titan', name: 'titan-all', version: '1.0.0'" Doesn't work anymore and I have to pull the resources manually?

Comment: I used maven to pull in titan-all and the classpath seems to be OK (that's where I got the info from I posted above). I don't use ES and Lucene, so I cannot verify Titan's integration with Lucene easily. You might inherit a newer Lucene version from some other project dependency you are pulling in.

Comment: This also happens if I try to run titan with the default config. Might be that someone else pulls Luscene or ES.

Comment: I added what I'm pulling.

Comment: So [check your dependency tree](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:listing_dependencies) for different versions of Lucene.

Comment: I'm getting org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0 in titan lucene and in titan es.

Comment: and org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0 with neo4j.

Comment: I am quite sure the neo4j dependency is overriding the titan dependency. You should remove neo4j from your titan project. And everything else you do not need.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I am trying to connect Neo4j and Titan

Comment: Then double check whether you actually need ES/Lucene for Titan.